# Javascript jump to top of page

Tags: javascript

I know how to jump to top of page when a button clicked using this code:

```
 document.body.scrollTop =document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
```

How can I jump to top of page when the current scroll position is greater than a specified number (such as 500)?

I want a solution which does not depend on jQuery.

Comment: I'm a little confused; does this not work for you already?

Comment: my problem is get current scroll position

Comment: I believe that's what `document.documentElement.scrollTop` is for... It returns the document's position from the top of the page (in pixels). When you set it to 0, you're telling it to scroll to the pixel at index 0 (the first pixel). There's more information on browser compatibility here: http://help.dottoro.com/ljnvjiow.php

Comment: i write this code but don't work . what's wrong? [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cxrs47w0/2/)

Comment: First, a function must be defined before you try using that function. `goToTop();` must come after `function goToTop(){...}`. Next thing is that code ran once, when you first opened the page. If you want it to run often, either use a timer (see [`setInterval()`](http://www.sitepoint.com/setinterval-example/)) to repeatedly run the code (ie. 4 times a second) or every time the page scrolls (see the [onscroll event](http://help.dottoro.com/ljurkcpe.php)). See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/cxrs47w0/4/ **--I'll make this an answer**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To repeatedly run code, you want to either use a timer (see [`setInterval()`](http://www.sitepoint.com/setinterval-example/)) or an event handler that occurs every time something happens. In this case, you'll want to check every time the page scrolls whether it has passed a certain point. This functionality is provided by the [onscroll event](http://help.dottoro.com/ljurkcpe.php).

```js
function scrollCheck() {
    if(document.documentElement.scrollTop > 120) {
         document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
    }
}
if(window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener ("scroll", scrollCheck, false);
} else {
    window.attachEvent("onscroll", scrollCheck);
}
```

```html
aaaaaaaaaa<br />aaaaaaaaaa<br />aaaaaaaaaa<br />aaaaaaaaaa<br />
aaaaaaaaaa<br />aaaaaaaaaa<br />aaaaaaaaaa<br />aaaaaaaaaa<br />
aaaaaaaaaa<br />aaaaaaaaaa<br />aaaaaaaaaa<br />aaaaaaaaaa<br />
aaaaaaaaaa<br />aaaaaaaaaa<br />aaaaaaaaaa<br />aaaaaaaaaa<br />
aaaaaaaaaa<br />aaaaaaaaaa<br />aaaaaaaaaa<br />aaaaaaaaaa
```

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't matter where your current scroll position is.

I have found you can get errors when `document.documentElement`does not exist.

Try this code

```
var body = (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop)?document.documentElement:document.body;

body.scrollTop = 0;
```

I made a fancy version on JSBin.

http://jsbin.com/qaqeqexaju/3/

```
<div style="height:3000px;">
  <button id="btnToTop" style="margin-top:2990px;">button</button>
</div>
<script>


function scrollToTop(){
    var body = (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop)?document.documentElement:document.body;
    scrollTo(body, 0, 1250);   
    return false;
}

function scrollTo(element, to, duration) {
    var start = element.scrollTop,
        change = to - start,
        currentTime = 0,
        increment = 20;

    var animateScroll = function(){        
        currentTime += increment;
        var val = Math.easeOutQuad(currentTime, start, change, duration);                        
        element.scrollTop = val; 
        if(currentTime < duration) {
            setTimeout(animateScroll, increment);
        }
    };
    animateScroll();
};
Math.easeOutQuad = function (t, b, c, d) {
    t /= d;
    return -c * t*(t-2) + b;
}
document.getElementById("btnToTop").onclick = scrollToTop;

</script>
```